# How to uninstall part of a bundle with out deleting it in the programs window?

Tags: c#, wix, bootstrapper, burn, uninstallation

I'm making a custom `Bootstrapper` to install multiple MSI depending on what the user wants to install. So far everything works fine, but I would like to be able run the installer again and choose which MSI to uninstall. If all installed MSI are going to be uninstalled, then remove the bundle else leave it so that the user can add or remove another MSI.

I was thinking of doing something like this in the `PlanPackageBegin` event handler:

```
if (WisState == State.Uninstalling)
        {
            if (e.PackageId.Equals("MSI1", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                if (requestMSI1 == RequestState.Present)
                {
                    e.State = RequestState.None;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.State = RequestState.Absent;
                }
            }
}
```

And then in the PlanComplete event handler I start:

```
Bootstrapper.Engine.Apply(System.IntPtr.Zero);
```

But then the bundle gets uninstall as well.

How can I prevent the uninstall of my bundle if not all MSI are going to be uninstalled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to work my way around it.

Instead of planning an uninstall I planned a repair to prevent my bundle from being uninstalled. And to remove it when all MSI are being uninstalled I plan a uninstall.

```
if (requestMSI1 == RequestState.Absent && requestMSI2 == RequestState.Absent)
{
    this.WisState = State.FullUninstalling;
    Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);
}
else
{
    this.WisState = State.Uninstalling;
    Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Repair);
}
```

I then check in the `PlanPackageBegin` if I'm Uninstalling (not FullUninstalling):

```
if (WisState == State.Uninstalling)
{
    if (e.PackageId.Equals("MSI1", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        if (requestMSI1 == RequestState.Absent)
        {
            e.State = RequestState.Absent;
        }
        else
        {
            e.State = RequestState.None;
        }
    }
    else if (e.PackageId.Equals("MSI2", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        if ("requestMSI" == RequestState.Absent)
        {
            e.State = RequestState.Absent;
        }
        else
        {
            e.State = RequestState.None;
        }
    }
}
```

And if I'm FullUninstalling I let the `Bootstrapper` handle the planning it self.

Note that WisState and requestMSI1/2 are variables I change depending on what my UI is supposed to show and the choose of the user.